# Sending email on travis

Tags: python, travis-ci

I am trying to run pytest on travisCI and the test fails when trying to send the email

**the class**

```
class AdminChangeLocation(Resource):
    """Admin can change the destination of the parcel"""
    @jwt_required
    def put(self, parcelid):
        payload = api.payload
        if not payload:
            return {'status': 'failed', 'message': 'please provide a json data'}, 400
        if not all(key in payload for key in ['location']):
            return {'status': 'failed', 'message': 'please provide the destination'}, 400
        check_empty = CheckRequired(payload)
        checked_empty = check_empty.check_data_payload()
        if not checked_empty:
            return {'status': 'failed', 'message': 'bad request no empty value allowed'}, 400
        parcel = ParcelModel()
        parcels = parcel.get_parcel(parcelid)
        current_user = get_jwt_identity()
        role = current_user['role']
        if not role == 'admin':
            return {'status': 'failed', 'message': 'Unauthorised. you are not allowed'}, 403
        if not parcels:
            return {'status': 'failed', 'message': 'parcel ID does not exist', "data": parcels}, 404
        change = parcel.change_location(payload['location'], parcelid)
        if not change:
            return {'status': 'failed', 'message': 'There was an error processing data'}, 500
        parcels['current_location'] = payload['location']
        # get the user_id
        user_id = parcels["user_id"]
        # Get the user email
        user = UserModel()
        user_data = user.get_user_email(user_id)
        user_email = user_data[1]
        message = "Hey Customer the current location of your parcel " + parcelid + " is now in\n" \
                                                                                   "" + parcels['current_location']
        email = SendMail()
        email.send_mail(message, user_email, "Parcel update")
        return {'status': 'success', 'message': 'Waiting for confirmation', "data": parcels}, 202
```

**the test**

```
"""This test case tets the parcel test cases"""
    def test_admin_change_location(self):
        """Test API if it adds a parcel(POST)"""
        data = {"email": "admin@gmail.com",
                "password": "admin",
                "role": "admin"}
        data2 = {"email": "langatchirchir@gmail.com",
                 "password": "kevin12345",
                 "role": "user"}
        location = {"location": "Nairobi"}
        res = self.client().post("api/v2/auth/signup", json=self.admin)
        res2 = self.client().post("api/v2/auth/login", json=data)
        data = json.loads(res2.get_data(as_text=True))
        token_admin = data['data']['token']
        res = self.client().post("api/v2/auth/signup", json=self.user)
        res2 = self.client().post("api/v2/auth/login", json=data2)
        data = json.loads(res2.get_data(as_text=True))
        token_user = data['data']['token']
        res = self.client().post("api/v2/parcels", json=self.parcel, headers=dict(Authorization="Bearer " + token_user))
        data = json.loads(res.get_data(as_text=True))
        order_id = data['parcel']['order_no']
        res = self.client().put("api/v2/parcels/" + order_id + "/presentLocation", json=location,
                                headers=dict(Authorization="Bearer " + token_admin))
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 202)
        self.assertIn("Nairobi", str(res.data))
```

**Travis.yml**

```
language: python

python:
  - "3.6"

install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - pip install pytest
  - pip install pytest-cov
  - pip install coveralls
  - pip install psycopg2-binary

services:
  - postgresql

before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database send_it_test;' -U postgres
  - export DB_TEST="dbname='send_it_test' host='localhost' port='5432' user='postgres' password=''"
  - export FLASK_ENV=testing
#  email variables have been set on travis .env

script:
  - pytest --cov=app/

after_success:
  - coveralls
```

Comment: Where is `SendMail` defined and are you authorized to send email from Travis?

Comment: After some research I found out that all SMTP port are blocked on travisci. I added an if statement on *SendMail* so as to not to send the mail

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution. Since Travis has blocked all SMTP ports I have bypassed the test using an if function to check if the env is testing
here is my code

```
class SendMail:
def __init__(self):
    pass

def send_mail(self, message, to, subject):
    # Gmail Sign In
    if not os.getenv('FLASK_ENV') == 'testing':
        gmail_sender = os.getenv("EMAIL")
        gmail_passwd = os.getenv("EMAIL_PASS")

        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()
            server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

            BODY = '\r\n'.join(['To: %s' % to,
                                'From: %s' % gmail_sender,
                                'Subject: %s' % subject,
                                '', message])

            server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [to], BODY)
            res = "sent"
        except:
            res = "fail"
        server.quit()
        return res
    return True
```